# Как в таблице SQL отсортировать данные с одинаковым статусом?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Есть две таблицы. Одна "команды", другая "матчи". Как прописать запрос, который отсортирует команды у которых 10 и больше матчей (таблица матчи) отмечены как "Победа" (не "Ничья" не "Проигрыш")?

Comment: join двух таблиц, с условием на победу в where, group by до команды, having по `count(1)>=10` и сортировка по `count(1) desc`

Comment: @Mike Вот так? SELECT column_list1 (команда), column_list2 (статус)
FROM table_name1, table_name2
GROUP BY column_list1 (команда)
HAVING count(1)>=10
WHERE column_list2 (статус) = 'Won'

Comment: почти. откройте любой учебник по sql и расставьте все предложения в правильном порядке (я в тексте писал все в том порядке как оно в запросе, а вы зачем то where отодвинули). И зачем спрашивать так или нет, любой запрос надо выполнить и убедится что выдает то, что ожидается

Comment: А еще отсутствует условие соединения таблиц (в том же where, раз вы используете запятую вместо join)

Comment: @Mike спасибо..